# ExecSQL não permite que não seja alterado o campo

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7, zeos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Opa, galera.
Novato aqui

Sempre que clico em alterar e depois clico em salvar (sem realizar alterações de registro) me retorna erro . Alguma ideia de como sanar? algum tipo de verificação sobre se houve alguma alteração faça, caso contrario desconsidere.

Ah, estou ultilizando Delphi7 e Zeoslib conectado ao mysql

```html
{EDIÇÃO DE REGISTRO}

if Ativo = False then
  begin
  if cpfantigo <> txtcpf.text then
   begin
      dm.query_func.Close;
      DM.Query_func.SQL.Clear;
      DM.Query_func.SQL.Add('SELECT * from funcionarios where cpf = ' + quotedstr(trim(txtcpf.Text)));
      DM.Query_func.Open;
      if not dm.query_func.isEmpty then
        begin
          cpf := txtcpf.text;
          MessageDlg('O CPF  ' + cpf + ' Já está cadastrado no sistema',mtInformation,[mbOK],0) ;
          txtcpf.SetFocus;
          txtcpf.clear;
          btnNovo.enabled := True;
          exit;
        end;

   end;

  associarCampos;
  Dm.Query_func.Close;
  DM.Query_func.SQL.Clear;
  DM.Query_func.SQL.Add('UPDATE  funcionarios SET nome = :nome ,cpf = :cpf , endereco = :endereco, telefone = :telefone, cargo = :cargo where ID = :id') ;
  DM.Query_func.ParamByName('nome').Value := txtnome.text;
  DM.Query_func.ParamByName('CPF').Value := txtcpf.text;
  DM.Query_func.ParamByName('ENDERECO').Value := txtendereco.text;
  DM.Query_func.ParamByName('TELEFONE').Value := txttel.text;
  DM.query_func.ParamByName('cargo').Value := cbcargos.text;
  DM.Query_func.ParamByName('ID').Value := id;
  DM.Query_func.ExecSQL;
  MessageDlg('Editado com sucesso',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
  listar;
  end;
```

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Edgar, tenho uma sugestão. Coloque esse bloco de código dentro de um "try...exception", depois capture o código da exceção que ele retorna. Aí você coloca um "IF" e avalia se o código for diferente da exceção, dá uma mensagem, senão deixa "seguir a vida", sem travar a aplicação. Isso não dependeria de ficar avaliando se alguma coisa foi alterada. Talvez exista algo melhor para resolver isso, mas por hora essa é a minha sugestão.

Comment: Tive que refazer a ligação utilizando outro componente, mas fluiu.

Answer (score -1):

Faça uso do componente `Query`, `Datasource` e `ClientDataset`. Lá no clientdataset você marca quais campos fazem parte do update, quais campos foram alterados, quais são as chaves e também através da propriedade `Delta`, saber se houve alterações nos dados para posteriormente salvar. Você não precisa gerar o comando de `Update`. Ele gera sozinho.